# Roblox POST request

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to send a post request with Roblox lua and nothing ive tried works, if anyone can help please do.
This is what i attempted but it didnt work

```
--Unimportant webhook stuff
local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")
function webhook(url, title, message)
local webhook = url
local dataFields = {
  ["username"]="RPL Hook Service",
  ["avatar_url"]="url",
  ["embeds"]={
    ["author"]={
      ["name"]="name",
      ["url"]="url",
      ["icon_url"]="url"
    },
    ["title"]=title,
    ["url"]="urn",
    ["description"]=message
  }
}

-- The pastebin API uses a URL encoded string for post data
-- Other APIs might use JSON, XML or some other format
local data = ""
for k, v in pairs(dataFields) do
    data = data .. ("&%s=%s"):format(HttpService:JSONEncode(k), HttpService:JSONEncode(v))
end
data = data:sub(2) -- Remove the first &

-- Here's the data we're sending
print(data)

-- Make the request
local response = HttpService:PostAsync(webhook, data)
-- The response will be the URL to the new paste (or an error string if something was wrong)
print(response)
end
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: it does not send @Kylaaa

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you not get a response from the webhook? Are you getting a non-200 response? Does the code simply not execute? Are there any errors thrown in the Output window? What code actually calls this `webhook` function? Please update your question with some more details about what you expect to happen, and what is actually happening.